# Error when trying to build a flashcard app in C++ builder

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to write a flashcard app with a GUI.

I only have one Label on the GUI:

[image]

The idea is firstly to display an English word, such as "hello", and after clicking a button then display the translation. I am stuck at the first step to show the "hello" on my GUI.

It shows an error:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Compiling Project1.cbproj (Debug, Win32)
...bcc32c command line for "Project1PCH1.h"
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall TForm1::Label1Click(System::TObject 
*)' referenced from F:\C_PROJECTS\GUI_TESTFLASHCARD\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link

Failed

Elapsed time: 00:00:03.5
```

The codes is as below:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include<queue>

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"



class FlashCards
{
public:
    char* Word;
    char* Translation;

    FlashCards(){}

    FlashCards(char* word, char* translation){
        Word = word;
        Translation = translation;
    }
};

std::queue<FlashCards> LoadCards(){
    FlashCards q1 = FlashCards("hello", "bonjour");
    FlashCards q2 = FlashCards("what", "quoi");
    FlashCards q3 = FlashCards("who", "qui");

    std::queue<FlashCards> flashcards;
    flashcards.push(q1);
    flashcards.push(q2);
    flashcards.push(q3);

    return flashcards;

}

std::queue<FlashCards> flashcards;
FlashCards currentcard;

TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    flashcards = LoadCards();
    currentcard =  flashcards.front();
    Label1->Text = currentcard.Word;
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you had double-clicked on the Label in the IDE's Form Designer, which generated an `OnClick` event handler named `Label1Click` in the code. But you seem to have manually deleted that handler afterwards, but the project is still referring to it.

So, you need to either:

- re-add the handler back into the code in `Unit1.cpp`:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Label1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // update the Label's text here...
}
```

- or else clear the assignment of the Label's `OnClick` event in the IDE's Object Inspector, and delete the declaration of `Label1Click()` in `Unit1.h`